# Breadcrumb Navigation For Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, navigation

Is there an open source implementation of a breadcrumb navigation for the Cocoa framework?
Those path bars seem to gain more attraction these days (used in Transmit or Instinctiv) but the implementations I found are closed source.

Comment: Hey.  I developed the OS X breadcrumb trail for Instinctiv.  Feel free to PM me and I'll email you the source.

Comment: If only StackOverflow had a private messaging mechanism.... :)

Comment: I can be emailed at peter instinctiv.com (at mark left out purposefully)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out @Perspx's [PXNavigationBar](http://perspx.com/software/PXNavigationBar/).  The source is available on [Github](http://github.com/Perspx/PXNavigationBar).

You may also want to check out [NSPathControl](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nspathcontrol).